# Twitter bootstrap not working from local files

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

When I include my script like this - loading `bootstrap.min.js` from a local file on disk, it does not execute my browser code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" </script>
```

I know it can find the file, because if I introduce a misspelling in the file name, Chrome complains, but otherwise not. Same behavior from IE-Edge by the way.

However if I include from the cdn network like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Everything works fine. The setup was suggested in a Coursera course on bootstrap and seems to work for most people, but not all. I am kind of puzzled. Is there a browser/internet setting that is preventing me from executing bootstrap from the disk or something that I am missing?

Comment: fix you script tag first, `<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> </body>` and if it didnt work check your console and post the error

Comment: it looks like a typo issue to me see the second line doesn't seem to have the right script tag    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" </body>   should rather be <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Argh, you are right. Let me check. If that is the case I will delete this.

Comment: Sure enough, a formatting issue. Sorry about that, but thanks. Will delete this in a few minutes unless someone thinks I should not.

Comment: no it will help someone, someday

Comment: It is odd that I had no error message in the browser, but that I did get one when I misspellt the name deliberately.

Comment: Yeah, it is fine now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" </body>
```

To

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have not closed your code

**Here**

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" </body>
```

**should be**

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```